# Typeorm is overwriting my createAt date even when I am not using createdatecolumn decorator

Tags: postgresql, typeorm

I am inserting date in my database with a defined createAt date. I don't want to use now() as default in postgres. So I have create my column as such using typeorm.

```
@Field(() => DateTimeScalar)
@Column("timestamp without time zone",{})
createdAt: Date;
```

and when I am inserting in my database I am creating a date as such:

```
Date("2022-05-08 00:49:23").toIsoString()
```

and then create an object as such `Interaction.create({createdAt: createdDate})`, I later add this interaction to my array of interactions and save them:

```
await getConnection().getRepository(Interaction).save(interactions)
```

The createdAt value is always overwritten with the current date, I even checked postgres and I can confirm there is no now() as default for this column.

Any ideas how do I disable this autogen option?

Comment: I actually seem to be having a very similar issue. But in my case I have nullable true and default 'null' set and not providing date results in date being generated automatically by typeorm. Cant find the solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As I wrote in comment, I had a very similar issue. Reported in on Github (https://github.com/typeorm/typeorm/issues/9966), but eventually solved it myself.

The reason for the problem I had was that my build command was not emptying out dist folder and thus I had older files sitting in it, which Typeorm (by my design) was automatically loading and using.

So check if you have or had any subscribers, which are automatically loading and thus rewriting your data in the middle of calls.

Comment: Yes, it worked for me by itself the next day when I restarted my pc, Even though others changes were taking effect for some it appears that the issue was due to dist folder for some reason.

Answer (score -1):

You can use `@CreateDateColumn` decorator. [link](https://github.com/typeorm/typeorm/blob/master/docs/decorator-reference.md#createdatecolumn)

```js
@CreateDateColumn()
createdAt: Date;
```

Type ORM will do all the stuff for you. You don't need to set it, just leave this field alone.

```js
const entity = new Entity();
entity.name = 'EntityName';
// entity.createdAt = new Date(); // don't do it
manager.save(entity);
```

Comment: Please read my question carefully, I don't want to auto generate the date for the column createdAt